# How I can delete error in rc.local file?

Tags: boot

How I can restore to default this file in /etc/init.d/rc.local:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start() {
    if [ -x /etc/rc.local ]; then
            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_begin_msg "Running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local)"
        /etc/rc.local
        ES=$?
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $ES
        return $ES
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    do_start
        ;;
    restart|reload|force-reload)
        echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
    stop|status)
        # No-op
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: The file looks exactly like mine and I don't have any problems with it. So I assume you have a problem somewhere else. Maybe better to explain what happens and show us the error message(s) you get.

Comment: I mean to  remove""Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2". How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: I thought that this is a problem for system and it start longer and when I shutdown PC there is a blink of some command line.